# are there transfinite equivalents to non-integer real numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory, infinity

Cantor first envisioned the transfinite ordinals as a kind of 'extension' to the finite integers, where  followed on where ℕ left off and continued the sequence. In this way, we can see them as 'equivalent' to the finite integers in this way.

I was wondering whether there are transfinite numbers (which are useful, in that they are used/have been used in set theory) which are in this sense equivalent to the rest of the reals? Does it make sense to talk about fractional transfinite numbers such as ( *+ 1/2*), or to talk about uncountably many irrational transifinte numbers between  and  *+1*? If so, are they useful?

Comment: "finite integers" ? Every integer is finite. There are no infinite integers.

Comment: Perhaps the [surreal numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) are what you want?

Comment: The [long ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) is $\omega_1 \times [0,1)$ lexikographically ordered. If you interprete an element $(\alpha, r)$ as $\alpha + r$, perhaps this might go into this direction? The long ray is an important example in topology.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Since you mentioned it first, would you like to expand that comment into an answer so this doesn't remain on the unanswered list?

Comment: @MarkS. No, I only know about surreal numbers in passing, so I don't have anything more to say. If you or anyone else would like to write a full answer, please feel free.

Comment: This question is similar to, but probably not quite a duplicate of, [Can we embed the ordinal and cardinal number systems into larger, more convenient systems of arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/384195/26369)

Answer (score 0):

As upvoted in the comments, one candidate for what you are looking for would be the "[surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number)" (a.k.a. "the surreals").

The surreals are a system of "numbers" (which admit ordering, addition, division by nonzero numbers, etc.) that includes a canonical copy of the ordinals, while also including a canonical copy of the reals. Exactly as the question proposes, the surreals contain numbers reasonably named by "$\omega + \frac12$" and satisfy $\omega<\omega + r<\omega +1$ for all reals $r\in(0,1)$. There are actually more surreals between $\omega$ and $\omega+1$ than could fit in any set (they form a "[proper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory))", just like the ordinals do).

A dry but detailed introduction to the surreals can be found in Claus Tøndering's paper "[Surreal Numbers – An Introduction](https://www.tondering.dk/download/sur.pdf)". A colorful but less-detailed introduction can be found in Don Knuth's book "[Surreal Numbers (How two ex-students turned on to pure mathematics and found total happiness)](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/sn.html)".

A discussion/justification of the analogy the question raises of the form "naturals:ordinals::reals:surreals" is given in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621587/26369) to the MathSE question "[Can we embed the ordinal and cardinal number systems into larger, more convenient systems of arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/384195/26369)".